# How do I use Count in a SUM function with inner and outer joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thanks for helping me find a solution to this SQL I can't figure out.

In my SQL statement I have 1 inner join and 1 outer join. One of the summations requires a count of the rows returned from an inner join

```
Table 1             

Location |Date       |Column3 |Column4
1        |11/22/2019 |23      |3
2        |11/22/2019 |23      |4
3        |11/22/2019 |12      |5
4        |11/22/2019 |54      |6
5        |11/22/2019 |65      |7
6        |11/22/2019 |23      |8
7        |11/22/2019 |5       |9

Table 2         

Location |Date       |Column3 |Column4 |Column5
1        |11/22/2019 |1       |8.5     |06
1        |11/22/2019 |2       |8.5     |06
1        |11/22/2019 |3       |8       |06
1        |11/22/2019 |4       |8.5     |06
2        |11/22/2019 |5       |7.5     |06 
2        |11/22/2019 |5       |8.5     |06
2        |11/22/2019 |6       |8.5     |06

Table 3         
Location |Date       |Column3 |Column4 |Column5 
1        |11/22/2019 |3       |3       |1
2        |11/22/2019 |4       |4       |0
3        |11/22/2019 |6       |5       |1
4        |11/22/2019 |25      |6       |0
5        |11/22/2019 |65      |7       |1
6        |11/22/2019 |65      |8       |0
7        |11/22/2019 |78      |9       |1
```

My Incorrect Statement, with the need for the count in line 5

```
SELECT 
T3.Location AS Location, 
T3.Date AS [Date],
SUM(T1.Column3- (T2.Column3+ T2.Column4)) as Result_Numerator,
SUM(T1.Column4 - COUNT(T2.Column2)) AS Result_Denominator,
SUM(T3.Column3 - T3.Column4) as Plan_Numerator,
SUM(T3.Column4 - T3.Column3) as Plan_Denominator,
'Element Name' as Element

FROM Table1 T1 
INNER JOIN 
Table2 T2 ON T1.Date= T2.Date AND T1.Location = T2.Location
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
Table3 T3 ON T1.Date = T3.DATE and T3.Location = P.Location

WHERE T1.Location = '1' AND (T3.Date>({ts '2019-11-01 00:00:00'})) 
AND T3.Column5 = '0' AND T2.Column3>0 AND T2.Column5 ('05','06')

GROUP BY T3.Location, 
T1.CNY_CD,
T3.PLN_DATE,
```

I looked a some of the similar questions out there and they suggest using union all to get the count first, but I don't fully understand how to make that work with the inner join between T1 and T2.

Many thanks in advance for heling me out
D

Comment: I don't yet understand what exactly you want to select. Can you show the desired result please? And what are the tables' keys? Is it `Location` for both `table1` and `table3`?

Comment: What's your DBMS by the way? MySQL? SQL Server? ...

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: My desired result using Location 1 as an example would be Location =1 Date = 11/22/2019 Result_Denominator = 3 - 4

Comment: Without knowing what the tables' keys are, I can only guess what query it is you need exactly. But it seems obvious to me that the solution to your problem is that you should first aggregate what needs be aggregated and only then join. I've posted an answer showing this.

Answer (score 0):

RIGHT JOIN is confusing. 
Use a LEFT JOIN instead.

Table2 might also need a LEFT JOIN.
But then the criteria on Table2 should all be in the ON, not in the WHERE clause. Or it would behave like an INNER JOIN.

```
...
FROM Table3 T3
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 
  ON T2.Date= T3.Date 
 AND T2.Location = T3.Location
 AND T2.Column3 > 0 
 AND T2.Column5 IN ('05','06')
LEFT JOIN Table1 T1 
  ON T1.Date = T3.Date
 AND T1.Location = T3.Location
WHERE T3.Location = '1' 
  AND T3.Date >= CAST('2019-11-01' AS DATE)
  AND T3.Column5 = '0' 
GROUP BY T3.Location, T3.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select inner_sum = (Select SUM(...) as inner_sum from Table 1
inner join Table2 on Table2.Date = Table1.Date and Table2.Location = Table1.location), outer_sum = SUM(....)
... the rest of your statement
```

Read more: [SQL Subquery](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/subquery)

It looks like you can directly assign the result of a subquery to a column name, which is pretty powerful! However subqueries are slow, and I'm sure there is a better way by using unions.

```
Select SUM(...) as inner_sum from Table1 
inner join Table2 on Table2.Date = Table1.Date and Table2.location = Table1.location
UNION
Select SUM(...) as outer join
....
```

Comment: Will this allow me to use the Count function in the Sum on line 5?

Comment: Yes it should, because from what I understand, the problem you're having is to get the sum from just the inner join first, and then the sum from the outer join right?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown an expected result in your request and haven't told us what the tables' keys are. I am assuming the following keys:

- table1 (location, date)
- table2 (none)
- table3 (location, date)

It also seems (but I may be wrong) that you want one result row per location and date. This means you must aggregate table2 data.

I don't know which table data is mandatory in your query and which is not. It looks like that you want to select from table3, which may or may not have matches in table1 and table2.

Many assumptions, because your request lacks all this information. Please describe your tables, their relations and your desired result more properly next time.

```
with t2 as
(
  select location, date, sum(column3) as sum3, sum(column4) as sum4, count(*) as cnt
  from table2
  where column3 > 0 and column5 in ('05', '06')
  group by location, date
)
select
  t3.location, 
  t3.date,
  t1.column3- (t2.sum3 + t2.sum4) as result_numerator,
  t1.column4 - t2.cnt as result_denominator,
  t3.column3 - t3.column4 as plan_numerator,
  t3.column4 - t3.column3 as plan_denominator
from table3 t3
left join table1 t1 on t1.location = t3.location and t1.date = t3.date
left join t2 on t2.location = t3.location and t2.date = t3.date
where t3.location = 1 and t3.date >= '2019-11-02' and t3.column5 = 0
order by t3.location, t3.date;
```

With all this guessing you may have to adjust this query, but you get the idea.

Comment: Just a remark: I've used a `WITH` clause here for readability, but you could just as well put the aggregation query in your `FROM` clause, if you like this better: `left join ( <the t2 aggregation query> ) t2 on t2.location = t3.location and t2.date = t3.date`.

Comment: Thank you for the above, I am trying to review and understand what is going on. in answer to your question, there is no relationship key between the tables. Table3 is only summing against itself as it is plan data. The main issue I have is getting the count to work.